# Subtractive loop of values SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to build a loop that will insert in the result column the result of subtracting the amount has to individual invoice items and reduced it by the position of the outstanding amount in the amount column.

```
declare @beenpaid money
set @beenpaid = '80'

select @beenpaid

declare @invoice table (id int identity, amount money, result money)

Insert into @invoice
  values (10,70), (20,50), (40,10), (12,-2)

select * from @invoice
```

Comment: Have you looked into recursive CTE ?

Comment: Or better yet, a Tally (they're significantly faster than an rCTE).

Comment: What version of `SQL Server` are you using ? if you are using later version of `SQL Server`, you can use cumulative sum `sum() over (order by )`

Comment: What is the expected result given the values provided?

Comment: provide separate input and expected output..